# Configure tmux copy mode to also dump a copy into the system clipboard

Tags: tmux

When working with multiple panes, it's convenient to use the tmux copy mode (`ctrl+b [`) to be able to use pane-aware copying. However, copy mode copies into a tmux copy buffer, rather than into the system clipboard. Ideally, I would like a copy to automatically copy into the system clipboard too.

A basic starting point was to add this alias to my bashrc:

- `alias tmux2clip='tmux save-buffer - | xsel -i -b'` (on linux, requires xsel to be installed)
- `alias tmux2clip='tmux save-buffer - | pbcopy'` (on macos)

After I copy using copy mode, I run the alias and the text gets copied into my clipboard! Works like a charm, but always requires that one extra manual step.

It would be ideal, if that alias can trigger as a kind of "post tmux copy hook" that I configure in tmux.

The best thing I could come up with is this line in my `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key    -T copy-mode    MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xsel -i -b"

# similarly, I believe only needed for keyboard based copies:
bind-key    -T copy-mode    C-w   send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xsel -i -b"
bind-key    -T copy-mode    M-w   send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xsel -i -b"
```

This causes *any* mouse based selection (note: I prefer mouse selection over keyboard based selections) to trigger a copy of that selection into my system clipboard. The annoying thing is though, that it will always happen, i.e. not only in copy mode, just anytime I select something it happens. This turns out to be quite sensitive in practice, just clicking the window with my mouse to give it focus often already accidentally triggers a small selection (often accidentally overwriting existing content in my clipboard, causing me to sometimes paste completely different stuff than intended).

I searched many similar questions but haven't been able to find any satisfying answers. I would really hope to find a way to get a kind of "post tmux copy hook" where I can insert my copy-to-clipboard command.

I use Ubuntu 18.04, with tmux 2.6. Please also be aware that I use mouse mode in my `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g mouse on
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. I've been wanting this for many months now already, and all of my revived efforts have only led to lost time :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want tmux to enter copy mode when you drag on the pane, then unbind MouseDrag1Pane in the root table (unbind -n MouseDrag1Pane).

Comment: Awesome, this seems to work pretty well! Still, a kind of "post copy hook" would be nicer, but this seems to work as well :)

I never realized that selecting text by mouse entered copy mode already. Why would it do that? Did it always dump stuff into the tmux copy buffer when selecting text (but did I just not realize that)?

Comment: I marked it as answered for now, but still hoping for a better answer if possible :)

Comment: By default dragging will enter copy mode and start the selection and ending the selection with the mouse will copy because MouseDragEnd1Pane is fired in both cases. Copying always copies to a tmux buffer.